# How to get record of network traffic in and out on Blackberry java programming

Tags: blackberry, java-me, network-programming

I want to make application to control network traffic in blackberry java programming.
Example : I want to know how much traffic radio in or out today in my blackberry devices, like  :

-Traffic radio in today : 1,29MB

-Traffic radio out today : 81.83kB

To get that number, what should i do?
Anyone can give me the source code to do that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RadioInfo.getNumberOfPacketsSent](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioInfo.html#getNumberOfPacketsSent%28%29)

[RadioInfo.getNumberOfPacketsReceived](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/RadioInfo.html#getNumberOfPacketsReceived%28%29)

But AFAIK, these methods return the number of bytes sent/received since the BB was powered on, so not sure you can have the number of bytes for a given day.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks smith :)
Thats very helping..
and i want to ask you more about WLAN, can i get the name of the WLAn im currently connected?
Thanks anyway

Comment: Yes, have a look at `WLANInfo.getAPIInfo()`. The returned object contains info about the current AP. (It returns null if Wi-Fi is not connected).

Comment: I already got it smith :)
And the last problem i encountered is how to get the number of packet sent/received via WLAN like i get via radioInfo.
u have any advice?
Anyway thank you, u help me a lot :)

Comment: You could register an `WLANConnectionListener` and keep track of the bytes sent/received only when in WLAN.

Comment: But only got 2 methods in WLANConnectionListener, networkConnected() and networkDisconnected().
How i can get the bytes sent/received?

Comment: You could register the listener at startup, so you know when you are connected by Wi-Fi. When you get disconnected, store the current total number of bytes sent in a variable (e.g.: `numBytesWifi`). When connected again, you perform the substraction: `numBytesNonWifi = RadioInfo.getNumberOfPacketsSent - numBytesWifi`. So at any given time when connected, `numBytesWifi` = RadioInfo.getNumberOfPacketsSent - numBytesNonWifi`. Something like that.

Comment: Something like this smith?
WLANConnectionListener listener = new WLANConnectionListener() 
{
 public void networkConnected() {
 numBytesNonWifi = (int ) RadioInfo.getNumberOfPacketsSent() - numBytesWifi;
 numBytesWifi = (int) RadioInfo.getNumberOfPacketsSent() - numBytesNonWifi;
 }
 public void networkDisconnected(int arg0) {
 numBytesWifi = (int) RadioInfo.getNumberOfPacketsSent();
 }
              // …
};
  WLANInfo.addListener(listener);

Comment: Keep in mind this approach is very brittle, as we're assuming when the BB is connected to a Wi-Fi AP no traffic goes through BIS or BES. This is actually not true, since each app can select the Transport Type it wants. If you finally go this way, change the vars types to long, or else you could lost info in the downcasting to int.

Comment: Ok got it, i change int into long. But im still dont have any idea,how to get wifi traffic, because when put some Dialog.alert("Connect") inside listener NetworkConnected, i cant see pop up dialog appear, so i assume NetworkConnected() is not working maybe?